# Hibernate unidirectional one-to-one mapping

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following table structure.
(The unique constraint is to avoid multiple 'details' to the same employee - I can't change the db structure).

https://i.ibb.co/r3pYQFj/fk.png

```
create table employee (
    employee_id number(19),
    salary number(10),
    constraint pk_employee primary key (employee_id)
);

create table employee_details (
    employee_details_id number(19),
    employee_id number(19) not null,
    address varchar2(256),
    gender char(1),
    constraint fk_employee foreign key (employee_id) references employee (employee_id),
    constraint fk_employee_unq unique (employee_id)
);
```

Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "empgen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "empgen", sequenceName = "SEQ_EMP", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private EmployeeDetail empDetail;
    
    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
public class EmployeeDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "empdetgen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "empdetgen", sequenceName = "SEQ_EMP_DET", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;

    ...
```

I have a rest controller that receive a JSON like this:

```
{
  "employee": {
    "salary": 80000,
    "empDetail": {
      "adress": "ST EXAMPLE",
      "gender": "M"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to persist all the entities via hibernate (5.4.28) saving Employee as the first entity, then with its primary key, EmployeeDetails using it's parent primary key but I get this:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DCC"."EMPLOYEE_DETAILS"."EMPLOYEE_ID")
```

**Why it's trying to save the child before the parent?**

How the the class should be mapped?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because Hibernate thinks that by putting `@JoinColumn` on `Employee.empDetail`, `EMPLOYEE_ID` belongs to the `employee_details` table.

Try putting creating a property `EmployeeDetail.employee` and put `@JoinColumn` on that one. If you need a reference from `Employee`, use `@OneToOne(mappedBy=...)`.

- [How to use @JoinColumn](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)
- [Activate logging to see which statements are executed](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-logging-levels)

Comment: I get 'object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing'

Comment: Did you add the cascade-Property to @OneToOne?

Comment: Yep, but still not working.

@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 

AND @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID") @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) –